# Assembler and C programming linux -m32 (char-byte from register in assembler)

Tags: c, linux, assembly, cpu-registers

I'm very new to assembly programming, I wrote a function in C which need to call another function in assembly. It seems like the register wants to give back four characters (bytes) instead of one, which is what I want.

Ignore the code after the jump, since I jump just to skip this part of the code until i make this work properly.

This is actually supposed to be part of my own simplified version of `sprintf` in C.
I removed some of my code just to get things to work. It's supposed to return the first parameter with a `%`. So, when I call this assembler function in C, i can write `printf("%s", res);` (or `%c` in this example) and it prints `%`:

```
.globl printpercent

# Name:        printpercent
# Synopsis:    A simplified sprintf
# C-signature: int printpercent(unsigned char *res, unsigned char *format, ...);
# Registers:   %eax: first argument
#              %ebx: second argument

printpercent:                       # sprinter
    pushl       %ebp        # start of
    movl        %esp, %ebp  # function

    movl        8(%ebp), %eax   # first argument
    movl        12(%ebp), %ebx  # second argument

loop:
    movb        $37, %bl        # lowest bits to %
    movb        %bl, %al
    jmp         exit
    movb        (%ebx), %dl     # 
    cmp         $0, %dl         # Check if 0

    je              exit        # if 0 -> exit

    cmp     $37, %dl            # Check '%' 


    movb        %dl, (%eax)     # if it doesnt equal any above/or default
                                # add to register %eax

    jmp     loop                # jump back to the start of the loop


exit:
    popl        %ebp            # popping standard end of function
                                # 0-byte ?
    ret                         # return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns int so of course the compile will alayws take the full register as return value. After all int == 4 bytes in your environment. You have to to clear EAX to ,make sure there are no random values in it.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily clear a register by using xor, so that the register is cleared before use again:

`xor        %eax, %eax`